# Memory leak error message from auval tool

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, audiounit

I am validating an audio unit in auval (apple's audiounitvalidationtool), it returns:

```
--------------------------------------------------
AU VALIDATION SUCCEEDED.
--------------------------------------------------
```

but I get a leak and I do not understand how to fix this. Can anyone be so kind and explain to me what could cause such an output and what a fix would look like?

> VERIFYING CUSTOM UI
>   objc[27641]: Object 0x7ffc12937aa0 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
>   Cocoa Views Available: 1

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have not set up your autorelease pool correctly for your AU. For more info, check out these SO questions:

- [NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696472/nscfstring-autoreleased-with-no-pool-in-place-just-leaking)
- ["Object 0x84be00 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking" - but on the first line of the app!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373112/object-0x84be00-of-class-nscfstring-autoreleased-with-no-pool-in-place-just-l)
- [NSThread with _NSAutoreleaseNoPool error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249022/nsthread-with-nsautoreleasenopool-error)
- [performSelectorInBackground gives "autoreleased with no pool in place" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631585/performselectorinbackground-gives-autoreleased-with-no-pool-in-place-error)